# How to create column cards in angular?

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to create column cards in angular. Here is the example.

```
The main card part is
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
      <div class="card">
        <h3>Card 1</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
      </div>

      <div class="column">
      <div class="card">
        <h3>Card 2</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
      </div>

      <div class="column">
      <div class="card">
        <h3>Card 3</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
      </div>

      <div class="column">
      <div class="card">
        <h3>Card 4</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
      <div class="card">
        <h3>Card 5</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
      <div class="card">
        <h3>Card 6</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xgnoqv?file=src/app/app.component.html)

The outcome likes:

[image]

However I have 100 more cards. It is dynamic, therefore I can't manually do it. What I want is to use `*NgFor` loop, can we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course, you can use the ngFor directive.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" *ngFor="let card of [1,2,3,4,5]">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>Card 1</h3>
      <p>Some text</p>
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here a link where you can find more information about ngFor.

https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Comment: The thing is that if there are many cards then it will occupy all screen height. I want to limit for example 2 rows then use pagination. Not sure how to set `div` css?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, To How to create column cards in angular?

HTML Code:

```
<div ng-controller="gridListDemoCtrl as vm" flex="" ng-cloak="" class="gridListdemoDynamicTiles" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-grid-list md-cols-sm="1" md-cols-md="2" md-cols-gt-md="6" md-row-height-gt-md="1:1" md-row-height="4:3" md-gutter="8px" md-gutter-gt-sm="4px">

    <md-grid-tile ng-repeat="tile in vm.tiles" md-rowspan="{{tile.span.row}}" md-colspan="{{tile.span.col}}" md-colspan-sm="1">
      <md-card layout-fill ng-class="tile.background">
        <md-card-title>
          <md-card-title-text>
            <span class="md-headline">Action buttons</span>
          </md-card-title-text>
        </md-card-title>
      </md-card>
    </md-grid-tile>
  </md-grid-list>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.gridListdemoDynamicTiles md-icon {
  width: 50%;
  height: 30%; }

.gridListdemoDynamicTiles md-icon svg {
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%; }

.gridListdemoDynamicTiles .s64 {
  font-size: 64px; }

.gridListdemoDynamicTiles .s32 {
  font-size: 48px; }

.gridListdemoDynamicTiles md-icon.fa {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 0; }

.gridListdemoDynamicTiles md-icon.s32 span {
  padding-left: 8px; }

.gridListdemoDynamicTiles md-grid-list {
  margin: 8px; }

.gridListdemoDynamicTiles .gray {
  background: #f5f5f5; }

.gridListdemoDynamicTiles .green {
  background: #b9f6ca; }

.gridListdemoDynamicTiles .yellow {
  background: #ffff8d; }

.gridListdemoDynamicTiles .blue {
  background: #84ffff; }

.gridListdemoDynamicTiles .darkBlue {
  background: #80d8ff; }

.gridListdemoDynamicTiles .deepBlue {
  background: #448aff; }

.gridListdemoDynamicTiles .purple {
  background: #b388ff; }

.gridListdemoDynamicTiles .lightPurple {
  background: #8c9eff; }

.gridListdemoDynamicTiles .red {
  background: #ff8a80; }

.gridListdemoDynamicTiles .pink {
  background: #ff80ab; }

.gridListdemoDynamicTiles md-grid-tile {
  transition: all 300ms ease-out 50ms; }

.gridListdemoDynamicTiles md-grid-tile md-icon {
  padding-bottom: 32px; }

.gridListdemoDynamicTiles md-grid-tile md-grid-tile-footer {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.68);
  height: 36px; }

.gridListdemoDynamicTiles md-grid-tile-footer figcaption {
  width: 100%; }

.gridListdemoDynamicTiles md-grid-tile-footer figcaption h3 {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center; }
```

JavaScript Code:

```
angular
  .module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])
  .controller('gridListDemoCtrl', function($scope) {

    this.tiles = buildGridModel({
            icon : "avatar:svg-",
            title: "Svg-",
            background: ""
          });

    function buildGridModel(tileTmpl){
      var it, results = [ ];

      for (var j=0; j<11; j++) {

        it = angular.extend({},tileTmpl);
        it.icon  = it.icon + (j+1);
        it.title = it.title + (j+1);
        it.span  = { row : 1, col : 1 };

        switch(j+1) {
          case 1:
            it.background = "red";
            it.span.row = it.span.col = 2;
            break;

          case 2: it.background = "green";         break;
          case 3: it.background = "darkBlue";      break;
          case 4:
            it.background = "blue";
            it.span.col = 2;
            break;

          case 5:
            it.background = "yellow";
            it.span.row = it.span.col = 2;
            break;

          case 6: it.background = "pink";          break;
          case 7: it.background = "darkBlue";      break;
          case 8: it.background = "purple";        break;
          case 9: it.background = "deepBlue";      break;
          case 10: it.background = "lightPurple";  break;
          case 11: it.background = "yellow";       break;
        }

        results.push(it);
      }
      return results;
    }
  })
  .config( function( $mdIconProvider ){
    $mdIconProvider.iconSet("avatar", 'icons/avatar-icons.svg', 128);
  });
```

I hope this code will be useful to you.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi I don't want to use javascript code. But thanks for your code.